# SQL - Multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql, path, sql-server-2012, cascade, cascading

I have the following situation:

[image: relations]

- Child1 has FK to Parent.ID
- Child2 has FK to Child1.ID and another FK to Parent.ID

Now I need cascading path when Parent.ID gets updated - so I added the 'ON UPDATE CASCADE'-Option to both foreign keys but as soon as I want to save the FK of Child2 (colored in orange) I get the following error message:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint '...' on table '...' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Why does this error come up? Updating the Parent.ID has no effect on the FK from Child2 to Child1 so the data should always be in a consistent state.

What exactly is a cascading path? If I remove the FK from Child2 to Child1, there are still two 'ON UPDATE CASCADE' looking at Parent.ID, but it's a valid setup. Does there have to be at least some kind of cycle to have multiple cascade paths?

Comment: Which SQL Server Version are you running. Since SQL 2008 MS implemented hierarchyid specifically to deal with such issues: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677213.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677191.aspx

Comment: You have two cascading update paths from Child2 to Parent- which causes the exception. This is a design flaw rather.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/

Comment: @Ralphi Thanks, I will read through that.

Comment: @FutbolFan I chose this design because (due to performance) I don't want to join Child2 with Child1 only to get to the data in 'Parent'. (Child2.ParentID links to the most-important dataset in Parent). In the link that you posted, if the FK Grandchild.Child2ID was removed, would there still be two cascading paths?

Comment: @ChristianSchröder Did you check out the link I posted above? That should help you redesign your process. In short, you might need to create triggers to do part of your updates.

Comment: @FutbolFan Yes I checked it out, thanks. Did I get it right that multiplate paths only exists if there are two (or more) paths from one table to the same field of another table? Because - in my example - removing the FK from Child2 to Child1.ID is accepted by the server. P.S.: I'm running on MSSQL 2012

Comment: @ChristianSchröder Yes...In your example, you have two paths to your `Parent` table going from `Child2`. While `Child1` only has a single path going to your `Parent` table. Hence, you get the error message when you update your value in `Child2` table and not in `Child1`.